# User defined literals which only differ in the return values

Tags: c++, c++11

This is what I want to achieve: I have two user defined literals with one taking a long double value and returning a slope, and the other also taking a long double value and returning a humidity. Now I want to use both UDLs in one scope. Unfortunately, in both cases the unit is 'percentage'.

```
struct slope
{
    long double val;
};
slope operator ""_perc(long double v)
{
    slope s = {v};
    return s;
}

struct humidity
{
    long double val;
};
humidity operator ""_perc(long double v)
{
    humidity h = {v};
    return h;
}

void func(void)
{
    slope s(0.0_perc);
    humidity h(0.0_perc);
}
```

This is not possible since the signatures of two functions cannot only differ in the return type.
We could use namespaces:

```
namespace slp
{
    slope operator ""_perc(long double v)
    {
        slope s = {v};
        return s;
    }
}
namespace hum
{
    humidity operator ""_perc(long double v)
    {
        humidity h = {v};
        return h;
    }
}
```

but I dare state that user defined literals only make sense when used 'unqualified'. We do not want to use them this way:

```
void func(void)
{
    slope s(slp::operator"" _perc(0.0));
    humidity h(hum::operator"" _perc(0.0));
}
```

Since both UDLs shall be used in the same scope, we cannot use 'using' because of the ambiguity it creates:

```
using namespace slp;
using namespace hum;
```

or

```
using slp::operator ""_perc;
using hum::operator ""_perc;
```

So I am stuck.
Is there any - preferably elegant - way to achieve what I want?

Comment: you can also using namespace in function local.

Comment: I re-read your question, I think you should return a `percent` class and make constructor that take `percent` in both class.

Comment: Why are the operators both called `_perc` instead of `_slope` and `_humidity`, respectively?

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph The name of the operator should reflect the unit which has been used. For lengths, I would call the operator _m or _cm, not _length.

Comment: @HJP That depends on the usage (maybe there’s only a single unit per quantity in your application), but either way “percentage” isn’t a unit. It’s a way of formatting fractions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious solution is to come up with different names.

If you prefer to keep "percent" as a quantity, you can use a percent class and define constructors, per [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61408255/user-defined-literals-which-only-differ-in-the-return-values#comment108631555_61408255):

```
struct Percent {
    long double value;
    explicit constexpr Percent(long double v)
        : value{v}
    {
    }
};

constexpr Percent operator""_perc(long double v) noexcept
{
    return Percent(v);
}

struct slope {
    long double val;
    explicit slope(Percent pc)
        : val{pc.value}
    {
    }
};

// humidity similar
```

You can define `explicit` conversion operators if you need `slope` and `humidity` to be aggregates.

Answer (score 0):

You might cheat by creating extra scope (as lambda immediately executed):

```
void func(void)
{
    auto s = [](){ using namespace slp; return 0.0_perc; }(); // slope
    auto h = [](){ using namespace hum; return 0.0_perc; }(); // humidity
    // ...
}
```

Comment: While technically possible (though I did not try), I could then as well use the qualified version of the operator call which I showed in my question.